# Should I keep the 62.5% font-size with Modular Scale?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, modular-scale

I am currently using the underscores.me WordPress starter theme to build a WordPress theme. I have just started using [Modular Scale](https://github.com/Team-Sass/modular-scale) for typography. I noticed that by default underscores.me uses 62.5% for the html font size. Would it be safe to remove it and just use 1rem for my base font size? I also plan to have different font sizes at different breakpoints so it seems like the 62.5% might get in the way. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most browser use a default font-size of 16px. The reason people use the 62.5% rule is because `16px * 0.625 = 10px`. When you make a em-based website it is easier to do the math from 10px than 16px. So, imho, it is ok to drop.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. The comment in the CSS after 62.5% says /* Corrects text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units http://clagnut.com/blog/348/#c790 */ IE6/7 are not of concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your browser requirements. If you need to support IE8, your REMs would need to be backed up with pixels anyway. The reason for the 62.5% is so the maths is easier for EM based sites so 1EM = 10px. Other than that it doesn't do anything so you can drop it if you're using REMs, don't mind the maths (if you're converting to pixels in your head) and you're not supporting IE8 and under.

Comment: I guess I could try setting my base in pixels then use $breakpoint-to-ems: true; but I will get ems instead of rems. I appreciate your help.